# How to go to the first line of output in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsvim

When I hit Ctrl-Home in Visual Studio while editing code, I go to the beginning of the document. When I hit Ctrl-Home on the Output Window, Find Results, etc, I jump to the first tab in that tab group (for me, it jumps to Callstack).

How do I make this consistent?

I have [VsVim](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim) installed. That may be doing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Tools > Options. Select Environment > Keyboard.

Set Edit.DocumentStart to whatever you want the shortcut to be (Ctrl+Home). Make sure you set it to Global.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VsVim does this.  Another way to change this is to click on the 'options' button in the bottom right of your screen, and look for "Ctrl-Home" and say "Set To Visual Studio".

Comment: "click on the 'options' button in the bottom right of your screen" are you talking about in Visual Studio? Or something system-level like the language bar? I don't see an options button.

Comment: If you have vsvim installed, there's an :ex style bar at the bottom of your screen.  TO the right of it is an "options" box.  Unfortunately my original answer was for an older version of VSVim, it looks like the CTRL-Home item is no longer there.